# graph with a bridge

Tags: graph-theory

Please help me with the Proof that every graph with a bridge has at least 2 vertices of odd degree. I was thinking about contradictio, to show that if graph contains only vertices with even degree than it has no bridge, so there must be at least one vertex of odd degree, but we know that in every graph number of vertices with odd degree must be even , so there must be minimally two it there should be a bridge. Is that correct? or would you use something different? Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 2):

If a graph has only vertices of even degree, and you remove an edge, you will get a graph with exactly two vertices of odd degree. If the edge you removed was a bridge, the two vertices of odd degree will be in different components of the new graph. If you look at one of those components as a graph it its own right, it is a graph with exactly one vertex of odd degree, but that's impossible.